# Using the chain rule on $P \left( Y = y \mid X = x \right)$, with $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability

I have a probability of the form $P \left( Y = y \mid X = x \right)$, with $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and want to find a way to express it in terms of $y_1$ and $y_2$ separately. Would the following be correct?

$$\begin{align*}
P \left( Y = y \mid X = x \right) & = P \left( Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2 \mid X = x \right) \\
& = P \left( Y_2 = y_2 \mid Y_1 = y_1, X = x \right) \cdot P \left( Y_1 = y_1 \mid X = x \right)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ related to $Y$ ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Typo, sorry. $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. $Y_1$ would be the first coordinate of the vector, $Y_2$ the second.

Comment: Okay.  If $Y=\langle Y_1,Y_2\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_1,y_2\rangle$, then what you have is **correct**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\def\eq{\hspace{0.25ex}{=}\hspace{0.25ex}}\vec Y\eq\langle Y_1,Y_2\rangle$ and $\vec y\eq\langle y_1,y_2\rangle$, then indeed:-

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\vec Y\eq\vec y\mid X\eq x)&=\mathsf P(Y_1\eq y_1, Y_2\eq y_2\mid X\eq x)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(Y_1\eq y_1\mid X\eq x)\,\mathsf P(Y_2\eq y_2\mid Y_1\eq y_1, X\eq x)\end{align}$$

This is just an application of the Chain Rule for Conditional Probability.